# Add a value to all users in AD

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to set up dynamic distribution lists at the company I work for.
I want to use the company value in AD for a distribution list that everyone in the company needs to be part of.

Most of our users have the name of the company as the value, but after checking some users it appears that this value is not set for all users.

Is there a way to set this value for all AD users (by using powershell f.e), or get a list of users where the company value is not set to the company name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PowerShell ActiveDirectory module, which is included in the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT). Details on how to install it are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/remote-server-administration-tools).

Then you can use [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser) and pipe the results into [`Set-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser). Something like this:

```
$badusers = Get-ADUser -Filter "company -ne 'Your Company Name'"
$badusers | Set-ADUser -Company "Your Company Name"
```

You *could* do this in one line, but I split it into two so you can inspect the `$badusers` collection to actually see the users that you changed (just type `$badusers` into the PowerShell prompt and hit enter).

It may be wise to limit it to, say, 5 or 10 users just to make sure it works the way you want before attempting to change every user. You can do this by adding `-ResultSetSize 5` to the `Get-ADUsers` line.

This also assumes you want to change *all* user objects to have your company name, even administrative accounts. Keep in mind that this will stop processing users if it hits one that you don't have permission to modify. If you want to limit it to a single OU, you can use the `-SearchBase` parameter of `Get-ADUsers`, like this:

```
$badusers = Get-ADUser -Filter "company -ne 'Your Company Name'" -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my question!